# Comparing current data item to observable

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

I have a template which looks something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewContext = {
    nodeClicked: function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target)
        var data = target.tmplItem().data

        viewModel.currentNode(data);
    }
};
</script>
<script type="text/html">
<a class='${ Class }' data-bind='click: viewContext.nodeClicked, css: { selected: viewModel.currentNode() == this }'>${ Name }</a>
</script>
```

I want to apply a css class to a HTML element if my observable contains a value equal to the data object used to render that element. My problem is with the part where I compare the viewModel observable to the current data item. I tried:

```html
<a class='${ Class }' data-bind='click: viewContext.nodeClicked, css: { selected: viewModel.currentNode() == data }'>${ Name }</a>
```

and it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try using $data instead plain data?

Comment: Thanks nEEbz. @RP Niemeyer just beat you to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$data` to access the object being bound instead of just `data`.

Comment: urgh, you are just so quick in all things knockoutjs :P

Comment: Sorry @nEEbz :)  on vacation today, so had more time to look at SO.

Comment: Wow!! This guy knows everything! Thank you.